Positioning a piezo stack along the optical axis
I'm having a question related to experimental physics.
I need to move an optical fibre 50 nm close to a sample at vacuum and cryogenic conditions. The main problem is that my UHV chamber is very small (6x6 cm). The design is sketched below: Inside the top block is a piezo for fine alignment, and a thread with 0.5mm per pitch for coarse alignment.

My supervisor doesn't want to buy an expensive translation stage from e.g. AttoCube, so I'm currently looking at cheaper alternatives.
One approach that seems promising is to use a piezo stack for fine alignment (5 um range, nm precision), and a manual stage with a micrometer screw for coarse alignment (500 um range, um precision). The lower block holds a sample.
Does anyone know of a (manual or motorized) translation stage that

is small (e.g. 25x25 mm)
is vacuum-compatible
has um precision

Everything I've found so far (ThorLabs etc.) is too large (50x50 cm)

You will need a custom design for something like that. Thorlabs has a team that could help you, but they charge premium. Vacuum compatible and motorized sounds extremely hard.

Also, be careful sharing your research like that...  can kinda guess what you are cooking... this may not be something your advisor will like...

The actuators that precisely positioned the JWST mirrors sound like what you want. They position in 8 nm steps, with a range of a couple centimeters. Here is a video describing them. He has free plans so you can print them. How to achieve nanometer precision in space?
